# Verb for "try to account for something"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

In my writing I have the following statement:

> We tried to account for this issue by doing this and that.

Is there a single verb that be substituted for "*tried to account*"?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're looking for.  Are you looking for something like "rationalised" (that is, tried to explain why the issue happened); or are you looking for something like "compensated for" (like, if you were actually doing accountancy)?

Comment: I am dealing with the second case. For example, I know that my method to measure a given quantity has some weaknesses.

Comment: What is wrong with 'tried to account'? Have you tried a thesaurus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and comment suggest that you modified your approach but did not fully resolve the issue you are citing. As such, the following may apply

> We *adjusted* for X and Y.
>   We *tweaked* it to reflect X and Y.
>   We *approximated* for X and Y.
>   We *estimated* for X and Y.
>   We *fudged* it for X and Y. [suggests guessing]
>   We made a *guesstimate* for X and Y. [also suggests guessing]
>   We *eyeballed* it for X and Y. [for observable quantity issues]

Answer (score 3):

Trying to account for something usually requires thought rather than action, so your example doesn't really illustrate the question very well. Still, if you want an alternative to *account for*, I'd suggest *explain.*

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible meanings of "to account for" at play here.

> We **included** this issue in our analysis...
>
> We **factored** this issue **into** our analysis...
>
> We **compensated** for this issue...
>
> We **circumvented** (or **worked around**) this issue...
>
> We **confronted** this issue...
>
> We **overcame** this issue...

It seems like you really need to work on what you intend to say.

...One last:

> We **controlled** for this issue...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "considered" might be an option?